# How to reverse array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to reverse array, or map with descending order?

```
<tbody>
  {Array(10).fill(1).map((el, i) =>
    <ObjectRow key={i} />
  )}
</tbody>
```

`reverse` function does not work

```
<tbody>
  {Array(10).fill(1).reverse().map((el, i) =>
    <ObjectRow key={i} />
  )}
</tbody>
```

Comment: why it is not working? you fill an array with 1s, so reverse will be the same. try this `[...Array(10).keys()]` and `[...Array(10).keys()].reverse()`

Comment: How can you reverse array full of 1's? Note that `i` is not part of the array, but an index from the `.map()` function

Comment: How will you come to know that your array has been reversed or not? You are putting identical elements at each position.

Comment: Ya sorry, that was the problem, I used i (index) instead of array element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 mistakes here.

First you load an array with 1s, which means that you have identical elements inside your array, so `reverse` is pointless.

Second you use the `index` as a `key` inside your `map` method and not the actual reversed element (using `index` as `key` is not considered best practice).

The correct way should be

```
<tbody>
  { [...Array(10).keys()].reverse().map((el, i) =>
    <ObjectRow key={el} />
  )}
</tbody>
```